# Variables in import files

Tags: python, variables, import

I have one file with a piece of code that can be used in another multiple files.
I'm using the import file but what I'm struggling is to use the variable created on the file1 into the file2. Ex below:

```
#---Script in the file1 called test1.py-----------------------------------------------------------------
rep_date = input("Please enter report date (E.g. 01/01/2023 enter 010123): ")

#---Script in the file2 called test2.py-----------------------------------------------------------------
import importFile2
print("Date entered: " + rep_date) #--THIS DOESN'T WORK
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide us with much context regarding the file tree of the project or code used. But you might want to check [relative imports](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/).

Given the modules you're trying to import are not under the same directory, you need to direct your module where the function or module are located.